# JQgrid hide/show inline del button

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I need to show/hide inline del button in some rows but I see a bug with the hide inline del button.

I hide the button like this:

```
gridComplete: function(){    var ids = $("#tableLesVersions").jqGrid('getDataIDs');    
     for(var i=0;i < ids.length;i++){     
        var cl = ids[i];    
        jQuery('tr#'+ids[i]+' td:last div:first div.ui-inline-    del',jQuery(this)).hide();     
     }     
}
```

but when I edit a row and then I click on the inline save or in the inline cancel button,  the inline del button reappear.

If I set

`formatter:'actions', formatoptions:{keys:true,delbutton: false}`

It will never show the inline-del button even if i set :

```
gridComplete: function(){    
var ids = jQuery("#tableLesFlux").jqGrid('getDataIDs');   
  for(var i=0;i < ids.length;i++){   
       var cl = ids[i];   
       var disponibiliteVal = jQuery('#tableLesFlux').getCell(cl, 'disponibilite');   
       if (disponibiliteVal.indexOf("production") < 0){   
          //Show delete button   
          jQuery('tr#'+ids[i]+' td:last div:first div.ui-inline-del',jQuery(this)).show();   
        }   
     }   
 }
```

Someone have an idea ?

Thanks.

Comment: you could use afterSave parameter to call the function that hides the button, check the wiki http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:predefined_formatter